# retain type when deserializing from binary formats like CBOR

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

If I serialize a POJO to a binary format that distinguishes float from double, such as Smile or CBOR, is there a simple way to deserialize to a Map using the serialized type?  For example:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor.CBORFactory;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SimpleJacksonTest {
    private float weight;

    public SimpleJacksonTest() {}

    public float getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(float weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    @Test
    public void TestMapFromCbor() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new CBORFactory());
        SimpleJacksonTest jack = new SimpleJacksonTest();
        jack.setWeight(123.4F);
        mapper.writeValue(new File("jack.cbor"), jack);

        Map<String,Object> jill = mapper.readValue(new File("jack.cbor"), Map.class);
        assertEquals(Double.class, jill.get("weight").getClass());  // I want Float
    }
}
```

If I inspect jack.cbor, I can clearly see that the weight field is serialized as a single-precision float:

```
$ od -c -tx1 jack.cbor
0000000  277   f   w   e   i   g   h   t 372   B 366 314 315 377
           bf  66  77  65  69  67  68  74  fa  42  f6  cc  cd  ff
```

How can I get readValue() to retain the type as serialized?

Comment: As of 2.8.6 it will work. Float was always stored and tokenized correctly, just interpreted as a double by Jackson core. See https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-binary/issues/32

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figured it out for CBOR, but here's what I came up with for Smile.  I added the following inner class to SimpleJacksonTest (along with the requisite imports):

```
private class SmileNumberDeserializer extends NumberDeserializer {
    @Override
    public Number deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
        throws IOException
    {
        if (JsonTokenId.ID_NUMBER_FLOAT == p.getCurrentTokenId()
            && NumberType.FLOAT == p.getNumberType()) {
            return p.getFloatValue();
        }
        return super.deserialize(p, ctxt);
    }
}
```

Then I incorporated it into the mapper as follows:

```
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(Number.class, new SmileNumberDeserializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

Now the following assertion succeeds:

```
assertEquals(Float.class, jill.get("weight").getClass());
```

This all depends on the deserializer retaining the type, such that getNumberType() returns NumberType.FLOAT.